# WebKit (iPad) CSS3: Background transition flickers

Tags: ipad, css, background, transition, flicker

Got a problem with animating the change of background color via CSS3 in Safari / WebKit specially on iPad.

Attached two screenshots to show you the problem.

1. [Image 1](http://imageshack.us/a/img198/8530/bildschirmfoto20130201u.png)
2. [Image 2](http://imageshack.us/a/img401/8530/bildschirmfoto20130201u.png)

If i chosse a color, the inner circle should fade from the current color to the new one selected.

But there are very strange squares during the animation as you can see it.

The big thing is the background color of the whole app (background DIV) get also colored in the selected color. But here not at full opacity. Just very light via:

```
$('#bgWrapper').css('background','rgba(XX,XX,XX,0.1)');
```

This Element fade the color perfectly - also when i switch to full opacity.

The circle Element (`div#centerRing`) flickers all the time. Even if i attach the same CSS styles as on `div#bgWrapper` or change the color also via RGBA.

Nothing i've tried works.

`div#bgWrapper` fades the background perfectly.

`div#centerRing` doesn't.

Anyone out there who already has fought with this?
Best greetings,

Answer (score 1):

**Okay guys, got it!**

The iPad got problems with animating (spacially background color) on big elements.
My element was 1600px x 1600px, if a change the size to 800px x 800px and scale it a bit up (scale(2)) via CSS3 it works. Also when the element is upscaled again via CSS3.

Hope that helps.